# How to revert back to not require rasterize

Tags: photoshop

I used to be able to color any Text, shape, or image by just selecting the particular layer and use pain bucket tool for example. Not sure what I clicked, but recently when I try to do the same;  I always get the following message:

> "This type Layer must be rasterized before proceeding. Its text will
>   no longer be editable. Rasterize the type? "

I do not want to rasterize. Can I know how to revert back to the normal setup where I can do the coloring without the need for rasterize please.

It also seems to mess around with my selection.

For example - I have a circle shape in the middle with transparent background.

I used to be able to go Select>All followed by Select>Inverse and it will select the circle shape.

But now it selects the entire canvas when I select all but returns the following error when I Select>Inverse

> "Warning No Pixels were selected".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may not be able to color a vector object with paint bucket tool. Instead, can you try using the color option in the blending mode. That will retain the vector property and also apply the color.

The following applies to PS-CS6

In the layers palette, 
= Right click on the layer > **Blending Options** > Select **Color Overlay**